# raspberry pi B+ hardware PWM

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, pwm

Raspberry pi B+ has four hardware PWM. How to use them in C/C++. The less complicated solution - the better.

I found one working solution with WiringPi

```
gpio mode 1 pwm  
gpio pwm-bal  
gpio pwmr 1024  
gpio pwm 1 500
```

This solution works only for one PWM output (GPIO18).
I thinks it is because WiringPi is designed for previous version of raspberry pi (Model B+ has new PWMs on GPIO12, GPIO13 and GPIO19).

For controlling regular GPIO I found solution:

```
pi@auto:~$ sudo -i  
root@auto:~# echo "16" > /sys/class/gpio/export  
root@auto:~# echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction  
root@auto:~# echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value  
root@auto:~# echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value
```

But there is no way how to control hardware PWM.

Product https://www.pololu.com/product/2753 has reference to python library - that do exactly what I want.

Please no software PWM suggestions.

Thanks

Vlado

Comment: Why don't you read the source code of the working python library, and do the same thing (it uses WiringPi2 -- http://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python/tree/master/WiringPi/wiringPi)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2) is a a distro that can hopefully fit your need.
It provides PWM and Servo kernel modules. You can simply modify the kernel files under /sys/class/rpi-pwm/ to create custom PWM output. 
[Here](http://adafruit-raspberry-pi.s3.amazonaws.com/Occidentalisv02.zip) is the download link.